# How do I write a Python program that computes the average from a .dat file?

Tags: python

I have this so far but I don't know how to write over the .dat file:

```
def main():
   fname = input("Enter filename:")
   infile = open(fname, "r")
   data = infile.read()
   print(data)

for line in infile.readlines():
   score = int(line)
   counts[score] = counts[score]+1
   infile.close()

total=0
  for c in enumerate(counts):
      total = total + i*c
      average = float(total)/float(sum(counts))
      print(average) 
 main()
```

Here is my .dat file:

```
4
3
5
6
7
```

My statistics professor expects us to learn Python to compute the mean and standard deviation. All I need to know is how to do the mean and then I've got the rest figured out. I want to know how does Python write over each line in a .dat file. Could someone tell me how to fix this code? I've never done programming before.

I hope this question on-topic. I asked this in the mathstackexchange and got some hostile responses.

Comment: Did you find the crossvalidated FAQ?  This question should probably be on stackoverflow as the people on math.stackexchange suggested.

Comment: Perhaps migrate this to http://programmers.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: I don't get it, why do you need **writing** to file?

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do the trick:

```
def main():
    fname = input("Enter filename:")
    infile = open(fname, "r")

    numbers = []
    for line in infile:
        numbers.append(int(line))
    infile.close()

    average = float(sum(numbers))/len(numbers)
    print(average) 

main()
```

Note the simplified iteration over the file lines. The numbers are stored in the `numbers` list, then their sum is divided by the length of the list to calculate the average. Everything is done inside the `main()` function, which is called in the last line.

Comment: Might be safer to wrap the `open` call with a `with` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to comment Lev's answer and I just realised that the computation of the mean was sufficient. Since I've done it right now, you might peek at a way to get the standard deviation below.

```
def main(): 
    [...]
    sec_mom = 0
    for n in numbers:
        sec_mom = sec_mom + n**2

    var = sec_mom - average**2

    from math import sqrt
    std_dev = sqrt(var)

    print std_dev
```

Here [...] denotes what is inside of main() already, as above. In addition you might add "print *something*" anywhere you want in order to understand what is inside of that *something*. And since Python can be used interactively, maybe try inserting a line of code at a time into the Python interpreter to try the code for yourself step by step.

Comment: `sec_mom` can be calculated in one line with [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions): `sec_mom = sum([n**2 for n in numbers])`.

Comment: nice, I love list comprehension in python :D